# What motor do I need to mimic the opening mechanism of flower petals?

Tags: motor, mechanism

I am completely inexperienced in any technical areas. However, I need a small motor for a larger art project and was hoping that someone here might be able to help me.

I would like to build a flower that can open and close its petals with the help of a motor.

Does anyone have an idea for this? Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time conducting an effective online search because I simply don't have the terminology or the knowledge.

Comment: micro servo  ...

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Lucy, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: As @jsotola mentions above, the device you're probably looking for is called a "servo." I did a quick search online and it looks like there's a similar-sounding project [here on Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/Blossoming-Flower-Arduino-Powered/) that would walk you through the parts, software, etc.

Answer (score 0):

##### Type of motor

As jsotola has mentioned, you are *probably* looking for a micro servo.

Something like a Tower Pro SG90 (weighs 9 grams):

[image: Micro servo SG90]

Or maybe even smaller.

The size and power of the servo that you will require depends upon your design:

- If all of the petals are connected, via some mechanism, and they are all meant to open at the same time then one servo will probably suffice.

  However, depending upon the *load of all of the petals and the material that they are made of*, i.e. weight, you may require something more substantial, like a MG995 or MG996
- If the petals are to open *independently*, then you would probably need a servo per petal, which would increase the weight (if the servos are mounted next to the petals up on a stalk), and so maybe something smaller than a SG90 would be required. Obviously, if the petals are connected to the servos via a rod, and the servos are mounted in the base, then weight will not be such a major factor.

---

##### Control mechanism

You don't say whether you have the controller already figured out, but in case you do not, then you'd probably want something like an Arduino with a servo shield, and then a simple sketch running on the Arduino that just *sweeps* the servo arm from side to side.

For what it is worth,  a previous post of mine, [Overheating/Jamming MG996R servo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/8103/9176), shows the Arduino shield and a sketch that provides a simple sweep action.

However, there are loads of example out there, and the `Servo` library (by *Michael Margolis*) for the Arduino IDE even comes with an example sketch (actually a suite of examples) for servos.

However, this is beyond the scope what you asked (just about the motor), so I will not elaborate.